# how to reduce the time to take maven build

Tags: java, maven, deployment, build, server

My Work is to take the build and deploy in a machine. I can able to take the build by putting this command "mvn clean install -DskipTests -o" it takes nearly 7 minutes .

I want to reduce the time by adding memory size or by some other way

**Apache Maven 3.0.5**
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_72, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-44-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: what version of maven are you using? Also can you post your pom here, or at least your build xml?

Comment: Without knowing what the build _does_ we cannot advise you. Although I would say the building with `skipTests` for **deployment** is a big no.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few general hints:

- Avoid `clean`. Most plugins are very well aware if they must do something. For example: now everything will be recompiled. maven-compiler-plugin-3.x supports incremental, so it can discover if something should be compiled or not. If you really need the `clean`, you should contact the developers of the plugin which requires it and ask them for improvements.
- Avoid `install`, instead use `verify`. In most cases there's no need to explicitly copy artifacts to your local repository.
- Run Maven with multiple threads (`-T`). See `mvn --help` for the details.

Comment: Then how should i run . Tel me the command by